# Implementing advertising web strategies

Tags: terminology, ads

I realize this isn't a target programming question but I don't know where else to ask this question.

I have been asked to research "vokens", "big box media" and "leaders" in the implementation of a web strategy for a company.  I understand that "vokens" are those highly annoying animated floating ad's that appear over websites (that usually utilize Flash or Silverlight), but what exactly are "big box media" and "leaders" when they are referring to advertising?  Has anyone encountered those terms in their past projects?

After I get some clarification on those definitions I am sure I will have 100 more programming focused questions on them, but I will leave that for later.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting topic +1, nbot often questioned in StackOverflow, not often answered. But to my view its the perfect place as its mixes one dimension of an issue (marketing) with another dimension (elaboration/programming). Not sure what you mean by big box media, specifically as I think of many many possible meanings of that word combination.

> Advertising on the internet has never
>   been more dynamic than today, and will
>   continue to keep changing, shifting
>   and being labeled new words.

Where were vokens 10 years ago? exactly! So my answer to you would be: try to focus less on precisely bordered, trendy words which might be valid in the vocabulary internet dialects of the west but not understood by Japanese market leaders, and try to focus more on what concepts of web marketing/ strategies you find interesting to approach.

Whether it will be made in Silverlight or Flash or (what I realllly missed in your question) in HTML5, is indeed a programmatic question but first get your goals right, your audience too, and your strategies. Let go of the trendy words that are obsolete in a few years, and focus on what you nead, regardless of how it is called, now.

PS. HTML5 is rumored to be `a mighty flash killer`... I bet from there there will be derived a dozen new concepts, with their own intrinsic codenames :)

Good luck with your research!